# MSbuild Publish to a specific directory using batch file

Tags: .net, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net, batch-file

Following is the batch file for doing a publish to a publish directory

```
@echo off
start
    /b
    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
    /target:publish
    /p:SolutionDir="C:\cc\ttr\code\Com.IT.sln"
    /p:PublishDir="C:\cc\ttr\code\deploy\"
    /p:Configuration=Debug
```

*(wrapped for easier reading)*

It is not publishing it. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

When `start` gets multiple arguments the first one is the title for the new window. Try

```
start /B "" start /b C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe ^
/target:publish ^
/p:SolutionDir="C:\cc\ttr\code\Com.IT.sln" ^
/p:PublishDir="C:\cc\ttr\code\deploy\" ^
/p:Configuration=Debug
```

(should work with the `^` at the end of the lines, for readability, but if not just put it all into one line again)

Comment: It keep giving the follwoing error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution

Comment: Well, it is entirely correct. You apparently don't have a solution or project file in the current working directory so you need to specify one as an additional parameter.

Comment: It is building the project but says "Web projects do not support the Publish target. Continuing with the remaining projects....Any idea why it is not publishing to the specified directory